# Analytical expression of convex hull

Tags: convex-analysis, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Is there a method to find analytical expression of convex hull in higher dimensions if the analytical expression of points is known?

Comment: Are you talking about the convex hull of a finite set of points, or an infinite set?

Comment: Do you mean with software like http://www.qhull.org ?

Comment: qhull.org provides numerical computation of the convex hull